# How to synchronize Google Contacts and Gnome Evolution?

Tags: sync, android, google-workspace, evolution, google-contacts

I would like to synchronize my Google Contacts (also Android Contacts) with my mail client Evolution on Gnome.

Do you know how I can do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this after 10 seconds on google search, which seems to explain everything you want to know, and yet more:

http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8226-how-to-sync-evolution-with-googles-pim-apps

> A little-known feature in Evolution is the ability to synchronize your Evolution Contacts with Gmail's Address Book. This is a great way to get your contacts offline and still synchronized with Gmail. To set this up, go to Contacts and click File -> New -> Address Book. Change the Type to Google, give it a name, put in your username (without the @gmail.com), and optionally select SSL. Click Apply, and all your Gmail contacts should show up in Evolution's Address Book under Google -> *addressbookname*.

Comment: Due to changes in Google's authentication policies this no longer works. Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed I am replying to a very old 2009 post with one reply in 2015.  But I experienced the same issue in both Thunderbird and Evolution after a recent new install of Zorin Linux in July 2022.  So maybe my experience will help someone coming along later.

A website discussing Thunderbird, indicated the add-on developer was working on a fix to correct the problem.  But as of a today, Thunderbird no longer works with the last recommeded Gmail add-on, tbSync.  Since Zorin ships with Evolution, I decided to focus on finding a fix in Evolution.

By default, my version of Zorin ships with Evolution 3.36.  But I found there was an Evolution flatpack 3.44.  It installed, imported my previous Evolution configuration for GMail, and successfully read and updated my Contacts, Email, Calendar, Tasks and Memos.